# z-index issue with bootstrap dropdown-menu class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need to set z-index of dropdown in dropdown-menu class in bootstrap.I have tried to set z-index :1000 but its not working for me.

can anyone please guide me regarding that issue:

```
.dropdown-menu {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: none;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

z-index can be inherited, perhaps the parent div has `z-index:0 !important;` on it, so you must set `!important` to override it.

`z-index: 9999 !important;`

Or you have set menu items to have less z-index than the parent, so they get overlapped.

Comment: I cannot identify the cause of your problem from these few lines but trying to use so high z-indexes is a barbarian way to fix something. You will run into more and more problems if you try to fix it with z-indexes now.

Answer (score 0):

Wait a little bit! There's `display: none;` in your code. Remove it!

Comment: It should work. I guess your div shows up properly but is positioned the way you can't see. if the parent is of full height `top:100%` can mean that it would display just below the fold (so you have to scroll down to see it). Remove all styling from the div (except z-index attribute) and check if it shows up. It will.